# Using Package.json to create a folder in your $HOME/Sites folder

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm trying to make my life a little easier by trying to automate as much as possible when starting a web project.

I'm using the following script to get my gulpfile.js to get the $HOME folder and it's parent directory.

Gulpfile.js

```
const homedir = require("os").homedir();
var path = require("path");
var pathDir = require("path").resolve(__dirname, "../../");
var parentDir = path
  .dirname(pathDir)
  .split(path.sep)
  .pop();
```

I then use the following script which finds $HOME and names the file to match the parent.

```
key: homedir + "/.config/valet/Certificates/" + parentDir + ".test.key",
```

This works perfectly fine when the name has no special characters or spaces, if the parent has a name like 'A&B Taxis' it breaks.

I need the script to remove any spaces and special characters so the output for 'parentDir' is abtaxis.

I've come up with this to remove the spaces but it won't remove any characters yet.

```
const homedir = require("os").homedir();
var path = require("path");
var pathDir = require("path").resolve(__dirname, "../../");
var parentDir = path
  .dirname(pathDir)
  .split(path.sep)
  .pop();

var newParent = parentDir.split(" ").join("_");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parentDir` can be simplified to:

```
var parentdir = path.basename(path.dirname(pathDir));

   // should get rid of all non-a-zA-Z0-9_ characters.
parentdir = parentDir.replace(/[^\w]/g, "");

  // if you need it lowercase use this instead
parentdir = parentDir.replace(/[^\w]/g, "").toLowerCase();
```